# Why does the combination of the two functions give $-u_{w-1}2^w+u$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some boolean algebra and operating on bit vectors of $w$ bits $\mathbf{u} = [u_{w-1}, u_{w-2},...,w_0]$. I then have the following two functions:

$$B2U(u) = \sum_{i=0}^{w-1}{u_i\cdot 2^i}$$
$$B2T(u) = -x_{w-1}\cdot 2^{w-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{w-2}{u_i\cdot 2^i}$$

I was then told that they can be "combined" (not that much helpful to me) to the following
$$U2T = -u_{w-1}2^w+u$$
But how? I really do not understand how you can up at that formula.

Answer (score 0):

$B2U$ is a function that takes $w$ bits $(u_{w-1}, \dots, u_0)$ and produces its normal representation $u=\sum_iu_i2^i$.
$B2T$ takes the same $w$-tuple of bits to an alternative representation with the leading bit counting as negative. 
To 'combine' them, it's simply meant as $U2T=B2T\circ(B2U)^{-1}$.

We have $B2U((u_i))=u_{w-1}2^{w-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{w-2}u_i2^i=:u$.
Comparing it to $B2T((u_i))$, we get that
$$B2U((u_i)) - B2T((u_i))=2\cdot 2^{w-1} u_{w-1}=2^wu_{w-1}\\
u-U2T(u) =2^wu_{w-1}$$

Comment: Thanks! But still, I do not see $U2T = -u_{w-1}2^w+u$ anywhere? And that it what the "combination" is supposed to give, somehow..